# How to add "or" statement in excel formula?

Tags: excel

I have a formula in excel, I would like to check for "RÉF" or "REF".
it's only working for one criteria, I can't add both.

`=RECHERCHEH(10^10;STXT(A2;MIN(TROUVE({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0};A2&1234567890;TROUVE({"REF";"RÉF"};A2)));{1;2;3;4;5;6})+0;6;VRAI)`

This is my formula... it's in french but it's the same principle..

Comment: I believe the following is the English equivalent of the formula: `=HLOOKUP(10^10;MID(A2;MIN(FIND({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0};A2&1234567890;FIND({"REF";"RÉF"};A2)));{1;2;3;4;5;6})+0;6;TRUE)`

Comment: thank you for the translation, but its more like this : `=HLOOKUP(10^10,MID(A2,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A2&1234567890,FIND({"REF","RÉF"},A2))),{1,2,3,4,5,6})+0,6,TRUE`

Comment: `=HLOOKUP(10^10,MID(A2,MIN(FIND({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0},A2&1234567890,MIN(FIND({"REF";"RÉF"},A2&"REFRÉF")))),{1;2;3;4;5;6})+0,6,TRUE)`. I'm sure simpler solutions could be found were you to give a few examples with expected output and also clarify your version of Excel.

Comment: Also, be careful when you use online translators for Excel functions. I have yet to find one which can distinguish between commas and semicolons as separators within array constants and as argument separators within functions. As such, they tend to blanket replace them in the former as well, often erroneously. In your attempted translation, for example, `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` is - for English-language versions of Excel - a horizontal array, and so the resulting array passed to `HLOOKUP` would error.